# Why is my thread not ending?

Tags: java, multithreading, search-engine

Im pretty new to Java and to thread-programming especially. This code is mostly out of a pretty old book (2001) with samples and examples for a search-engine.
But its just not working
Now i don't know if i am making a mistake or if the author made it or if there are incompatibilities with different versions of java...i really have no clue! The oddest thing about it is that it works 1 out of 100 times ...
After hours of debugging i would appreciate any help!

SearchEngine.java:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import parsing.SourceElement;
import parsing.WebParserWrapper;
import query.Filter;

public class SearchEngine implements Runnable {

    private Vector linkHistory = new Vector();
    private int currentLink;
    private String beginAt = null;
    private SearchHandler searchHandler = null;
    private boolean searchInProgress = false;
    private boolean stopPending = false;
    boolean firstTime = true;

    public boolean searchInProgress() {
        return searchInProgress;
    }

    public boolean stopPending() {
        return stopPending;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void followLinks(String url) {

        if (stopPending)
            return;
        try {

            boolean drillDown = false;

            WebParserWrapper webParser = new WebParserWrapper();
            Vector sortedElements = webParser.getElements(url, "", "WITHGET");
            Vector contentElements = Filter.getFilteredElements(sortedElements, Filter.CONTENT, "matches", "*");

            for (int i = 0; i < contentElements.size(); i++) {
                SourceElement thisElement = (SourceElement) contentElements.elementAt(i);
                String thisKey = (String) thisElement.getKey();
                String thisContent = (String) thisElement.getContent();

                boolean goodHit = searchHandler.handleElement(url, thisKey, thisContent);

                if (goodHit) {
                    drillDown = true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(url + " -- DrillDown " + ((drillDown) ? "positive" : "negative"));

            if (drillDown) {
                Vector linkElements = Filter.getFilteredElements(sortedElements, Filter.KEY, "matches",
                        "*a[*].@href[*]");

                for (int i = 0; i < linkElements.size(); i++) {
                    SourceElement thisElement = (SourceElement) linkElements.elementAt(i);
                    String thisContent = (String) thisElement.getContent();
                    if (!linkHistory.contains(thisContent)) {
                        linkHistory.add(thisContent);
                        System.out.println("Collected: " + thisContent);
                    }

                }

            }

        } 

        catch (Exception e) {}

        if (currentLink < linkHistory.size()) {
            String nextLink = (String) linkHistory.elementAt(currentLink++);
            if (nextLink != null) {
                followLinks(nextLink);
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean startSearch(String url, SearchHandler searchHandler) {
        if (searchInProgress)
            return false;

        beginAt = url;
        this.searchHandler = searchHandler;
        this.linkHistory = new Vector();
        this.currentLink = 0;

        Thread searchThread = new Thread(this);
        searchThread.start();
        return true;
    }

    public void stopSearch() {
        stopPending = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        searchInProgress = true;
        followLinks(beginAt);
        searchInProgress = false;
        stopPending = false;
    }

}
```

SimpleSearcher.java

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class SimpleSearcher implements SearchHandler {
    private SearchEngine searchEngine;
    private String keyword;
    private String startURL;
    private Hashtable hits = new Hashtable();

    public boolean handleElement(String url, String key, String content) {
        boolean goodHit = false;
        int keywordCount = 0;
        int pos = -1;
        while ((pos = content.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword, pos + 1)) >= 0){
            keywordCount++;

        }

        if (keywordCount > 0) {
            Integer count = (Integer) hits.get(url);
            if (count == null){
                hits.put(url, new Integer(1));
            }
            else {
                hits.remove(url);
                hits.put(url, new Integer(count.intValue() + keywordCount));
            }

            goodHit = true;
        }
        if (hits.size() >= 3)
            searchEngine.stopSearch();
        return goodHit;
    }

    public Hashtable search(String startURL, String keyword) {
        searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
        this.startURL = startURL;
        this.keyword = keyword;

        searchEngine.startSearch(startURL, this);
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);}catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        while (searchEngine.searchInProgress());

        return this.hits;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleSearcher searcher = new SimpleSearcher();
        String url = "http://www.nzz.ch/";
        String compareWord = "der";

        Hashtable hits = searcher.search(url, compareWord);


        System.out.println("URLs=" + hits.size());
        for (Enumeration keys = hits.keys(); keys.hasMoreElements();) {
            String thisKey = (String) keys.nextElement();
            int thisCount = ((Integer) hits.get(thisKey)).intValue();
            System.out.println(thisCount + " hits at " + thisKey);
        }
    }
}
```

SearchHandler.java

```
public interface SearchHandler {
    public boolean handleElement(String url, String key, String content);
}
```

Comment: `stopPending` probably should `volatile` or `AtomicBoolean` - same goes for `searchInProgress`...

Comment: `while (searchEngine.searchInProgress());` can rather expensive and should be avoided. Instead, you should be using some kind of lock and simply waiting on it...

Comment: You might want to have a read through [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for some more ideas

Comment: You should also never just swallow an exception. At the very least, print the stack trace.

Comment: Wow, 2001. That was a long time ago. Java has changed a **lot** since that book was written. Multi-core machines are generally available and JIT compilers are much better, so code like this that might have "worked" in 2001 now fails in 2015. The language and libraries have changed a lot, too. No generics? `Vector`? `Hashtable`? `Enumeration`? I strongly recommend you get a newer book to learn from; this one will teach you a lot of bad stuff.

Comment: To address your question more directly, the code from the book appears to be buggy. It doesn't share data between threads properly, leading to race conditions and other misbehavior. We could spend time debugging this code and fixing it up, but really, you should get a newer book.

Comment: Finally, out of morbid curiosity, what book is this?

Comment: Haha guys...i know the book is super old...its called "Web Content Mining with Java: Techniques for Exploiting the World's Biggest Information"!

and to be honest...i dont like how it is written and designed...code and text are too mixed up..but it was the only book i could find so far that was focussing on this topic with Java...

But if anyone has a suggestion on what books might be helpful, feel free to share :)